# Lottery Discrete Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working in a lottery using a discrete probability distribution. The cost of 1 ticket is $1. The lottery in my country is to choose six numbers from 1 to 40. If you match the six numbers, you win the big prize, but you can win too by matching 5, 4, or 3 numbers.

This is an example of the prizes:

- matching 6 numbers - $2,200,000
- matching 5 numbers - $25,000
- matching 4 numbers - $400
- matching 3 numbers - $50
- matching 0,1,2 numbers - $0

I have to find the expected value.

I first calculated the possible combinations for each amount of matches.

- 6 matches - $C(40,6)=3,838,380$
- 5 matches - $C(40,5)=658,380$
- 4 matches - $C(40,4)=91,390$
- 3 matches - $C(40,3)=9,880$
- 2 matches - $C(40,2)=780$
- 1 match - $C(40,1)=40$

I'm not sure if I have to include 0 matches: $C(40,0)=1$.

Then, I calculate the gain for each match: prize - cost.

I calculated the probability for each match using the formula $\frac{1}{C(n,r)}$. But I'm not sure if have to include $\frac{1}{C(40,0)}$ because it would be $1$, which for me does not make sense.

Anyway, I organize all this on a table and found that my expected value is $0.59. I want to know if this is right or if I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seek the probability to "match $n$" given that you choose any $6$ from all $40$ numbers.

You "match $n$" when you have choosen $n$ from the $6$ target numbers **and** $6-n$ from the $34$ remaining.

---

For example, the probability to "match $0$" is $\tfrac{\operatorname{C}(34, 6)}{\operatorname{C}(40, 6)}$ ... the probability to choose $6$ from the $34$ nontarget numbers when selecting $6$ from all $40$ numbers.

Comment: ohh ok got it! So $\frac{C(34,6)}{C(40,6)}=\frac{1,344,904}{3,838,380}$ the I would add that to $\frac{1}{780}+\frac{1}{40}$ for the probability of 0,1 or 2 matches? That would be the only thing missing? Everything else is good besides de sum of $x\cdot P(x)$ that will change now?